# PowerShell - Alert on File Creation

Tags: powershell

I created this PowerShell script that runs on our web server to alert when a file is created in a folder (C:\folder\dumps). The purpose is one of our web services from a third party errors out when a file is created. I created an alert to show on a Cyfe dashboard using iFrame that refreshes every 10 seconds. When there is a file, the background color on the html page is red, otherwise it's green. One thing I noticed is that it seems the html file is deleted, then recreated every time. Is my code wrong? I know it's horrible but I suck at PowerShell and this was hodgepodged, but it works.

```
$StyleBad = "
<style>
    body {color: white;
    background-color: red;}
</style>
"

$StyleGood = "
<style>
    body {color: white;
    background-color: green;}
</style>
"


while ($GetCount -le 99) {
$GetCount = Get-ChildItem  C:\webfolder\dumps -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}

If ($GetCount -le 0) {
ConvertTo-HTML -head $StyleGood -PostContent $GetCount | Out-File C:\website\dumps\index.html
}

else {
ConvertTo-HTML -head $StyleBad -PostContent $GetCount | Out-File C:\website\dumps\index.html
}
}
```

Comment: `C:\website\dumps\index.html` will be overwritten each time by the result of `ConvertTo-Html`.  What would you expect to happen?  Does the script work as intended?  Also, hopefully the similar paths are not a miscopy and the directory being monitored for files (`C:\webfolder\dumps`) truly is different than the directory containing the status file (`C:\website\dumps`).

Comment: The script does work. The two directories are different and not a miscopy.

Comment: Very good then. It's wouldn't be feasible to rewrite the file in place because the color name and file count would be different lengths, throwing off the alignment of the markup that comes after. Plus, such selective rewriting logic is going to be so much more work for so little gain compared to just overwriting the file like it is now.  Also, typically I think `Set-Content` would be preferred to `Out-File`, but in this case it doesn't make a difference. You might want to add a `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` to your loop, though, because as it is now it's going to run as fast as it can at 100% CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you BACON. I was given this code from another source. This code is working much better.

```
$css = @'
<style "text/css">
    body{{
        color: white;
        background-color: {0};
    }}
</style>
'@
while($true){
    $color = if($count = (Get-ChildItem  C:\ecommerce\orders-acuity\dumps -File).Count){
        'red'
    }else{
        'green'
    }
    $style = $css -f $color
    ConvertTo-HTML -head $style -PostContent $count | Out-File C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dumps\index.html
    if($count -gt 99){break}
    sleep 5
}
```